# Why Mvvm approach is not working for my Calculator?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to work on MVVM using silverlight 5 and my xaml code is this:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="100" Width="350">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="+" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SecondValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="=" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Result, Mode=OneWay}" Height="25" TextAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0,5,0,0" Content="Calculate" Command="{Binding CalculateCommand}"  />
    </Grid>
```

And

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new CalculatorViewModel();
        }
```

My CalculatorViewModel.cs class is :

```
public class CalculatorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public CalculatorModel cc;


        private string _firstValue;
        public string FirstValue
        {
            get { return _firstValue; }
            set
            {
                _firstValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstValue");
            }
        }

        private string _secondValue;
        public string SecondValue
        {
            get { return _secondValue; }
            set
            {
                _secondValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SecondValue");
            }
        }

        private string _result;
        public string Result
        {
            get { return _result; }
            private set
            {
                _result = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }

        private ICommand _calculateCommand;
        public ICommand CalculateCommand
        {
            get { return _calculateCommand; }
        }

        public CalculatorViewModel()
        {
            cc = new CalculatorModel();
            cc.FirstValue = _firstValue;
            cc.SecondValue = _secondValue;
            cc.Result = _result;
            _calculateCommand = new RelayCommand(cc.Calculate) { IsEnabled = true };
            //This Calculate() is defined in Model class (CalculatorModel.cs).
         }    

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

And i wanted to define this calculate delegate in Model class(CalculatorModel.cs).According to what i understand this is what for Model class are meant. (**please correct me if i am wrong**).

**I done like this:**

```
 public class CalculatorModel
    {
        #region PROPERTIES
        public string FirstValue;
        public string SecondValue;
        public string Result;

        #endregion
        //CalculatorViewModel cv = new CalculatorViewModel();

        public CalculatorModel()
        {
            this.Result = "";
            this.FirstValue = "";
            this.SecondValue = "";              
        }
        public void Calculate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("check : " +FirstValue);
            Result = (Convert.ToInt32(FirstValue) + Convert.ToInt32(SecondValue)).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem is i dont know **why on debugging the value of Result, FirstValue and SecondValue are null** the delegate `calculate()` is called on button click but there is no output updated in Result.

**Could some one please correct me whats wrong in my approach of defining calculate() in Model class ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be updating the values in the Model. Databinding only works between View and ViewModel.

```
    private string _firstValue;
    public string FirstValue
    {
        get { return _firstValue; }
        set
        {
            _firstValue = value;
            cc.FirstValue = _firstValue;     // add this
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstValue");
        }
    }
```

and do that for SecondValue as well. Change the command so that the result is assigned to Result.

This tells you that your setup is not the most efficient or elegant. 
Consider

1. Make the Model INotifyPropertyChanged and bind to Model.FirstValue
2. or, drop the concept of a Model here.

When you make the Model implement INPC you can (should) remove the FirstValue, SecondValue and Result entirely from the VM. You can bind to the Model: `Text="{Binding Path=cc.FirstValue, Mode=TwoWay}"` and then make the Model a property:

```
   public CalculatorModel cc { get; set; }   // must be a property
```

Otherwise, the better pattern for 'repeating' a property is:

```
    //private string _firstValue;
    public string FirstValue
    {
        get { return cc.FirstValue; }
        set
        {
            //_firstValue = value;
            cc.FirstValue = value;           // add this
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstValue");
        }
    }
```

avoid storing data twice.

Comment: thanks for the answer but now on debugging i can see that the value written in text box are accessible but result is not updated yet. Any Idea why ? (I had made the changes you suggested for all the three , i mean for Result as well)

Comment: You mean this change: private ICommand _calculateCommand;
        public ICommand CalculateCommand
        {
           
            get { return _calculateCommand; }
            set { cc.Result = _result; }
        }

Comment: No, that looks wrong. Roughly: `new RelayCommand(() => Result = cc.Calculate())`

Comment: I need somemore help. By the two points you made in your answer do you mean to say that: ViewModel class is not good for having INotifyPropertyChanged. It must be done in Model ? Could you please explain me in detail in your anser which class should contain what ? (because in many examples i have not seen in model class they just do everything in ViewModel class so i am bit confused with that)

Comment: The ViewModel should always implement INPC. The Model may do so too. I'll edit a little.

Comment: And one more question when itried to do "CalculatorViewModel cv = new CalculatorViewModel();" in CalculatorModel class. So it gave a stackOverflow exception (I mean if you see CalculatorModel class i have commened thsi line but on uncommenting it gives this exception). I couldnt understand why ?

Comment: That's a separate issue but trace the logic together with `cc = new CalculatorModel();`. It's called mutual recusrion.